# How to call a function in a Stateful Widget from another StatefulWidget?

Tags: function, flutter, call, stateful

Hello I want to call the function that are inside the StatefulWidget of the formCliente class to clean the controllers.but I want to access it via a button that is inside the StatefulWidget of the formFinanceiro class. help me please! thanks.

```
      class _CadastrarClienteState extends State<CadastrarCliente>
with TickerProviderStateMixin {     
    body: Form(
      key: formkey,
      child: TabBarView(
        physics: physics, //NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          FormCliente(),
          FormDocumento(),
          FormVeiculo(),
          FormContrato(),
          FutureBuilder(
              future: getTrabalhaComCota(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
                  //   print(' chamada cota:${snapshot.data}');
                  return FormFinanceiro(
                      itemsCota: snapshot.data, formKey: formkey);
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              }),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

}
]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Streams to achive the same, please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
        body: MyApps(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyApps extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppsState createState() => _MyAppsState();
}

class _MyAppsState extends State<MyApps> {
  final changeNotifier = new StreamController.broadcast();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    changeNotifier.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  buttonClicked() => changeNotifier.sink.add(null);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        FormCliente(
          shouldTriggerChange: changeNotifier.stream,
        ),
        FormFinanceiro(buttonClicked: buttonClicked),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class FormCliente extends StatefulWidget {
  final Stream shouldTriggerChange;

  FormCliente({this.shouldTriggerChange});

  @override
  _FormClienteState createState() => _FormClienteState();
}

class _FormClienteState extends State<FormCliente> {
  StreamSubscription streamSubscription;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.shouldTriggerChange != null) {
      streamSubscription =
          widget.shouldTriggerChange.listen((_) => clearYourFormMethod());
    }
  }

  @override
  didUpdateWidget(FormCliente old) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(old);
    if (widget.shouldTriggerChange != old.shouldTriggerChange) {
      streamSubscription.cancel();
      streamSubscription =
          widget.shouldTriggerChange.listen((_) => clearYourFormMethod());
    }
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    streamSubscription.cancel();
  }

  void clearYourFormMethod() {
    print('Please clear your form here');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("FormCliente");
  }
}

class FormFinanceiro extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function buttonClicked;

  FormFinanceiro({this.buttonClicked});

  @override
  _FormFinanceiroState createState() => _FormFinanceiroState();
}

class _FormFinanceiroState extends State<FormFinanceiro> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          child: new Text("FormFinanceiro"),
          onPressed: widget.buttonClicked,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can run the code directly from dartpad here - https://dartpad.dev/c629242d7eb485809a87495629f8febf  When you click the FormFinanceiro please see the output in Console that should say "Please clear your form here". Essentially you are calling clearYourFormMethod() in FormCliente by clicking the Raised button in FormFinanceiro.

Comment: I can user the same  method for anther classes ?

Comment: Yes, you may use the same method for another class

Comment: Bluenile
I didn't understand why you used this code?


  didUpdateWidget(FormCliente old) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(old);
    if (widget.shouldTriggerChange != old.shouldTriggerChange) {
      streamSubscription.cancel();
      streamSubscription =
          widget.shouldTriggerChange.listen((_) => clearYourFormMethod());
    }
  }

Comment: For that you need to understand Lifecycle of Widgets. Please refer to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html . If a State's build method depends on an object that can itself change state, for example a ChangeNotifier or Stream, or some other object to which one can subscribe to receive notifications, then be sure to subscribe and unsubscribe properly in initState, didUpdateWidget, and dispose:

Comment: In initState, subscribe to the object.
In didUpdateWidget unsubscribe from the old object and subscribe to the new one if the updated widget configuration requires replacing the object.
In dispose, unsubscribe from the object.

Comment: So the code is simply unsubscribing from the old object and subscribing to the new one of widget updates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lift the `state` up:

1. Create the controller in `_CadastrarClienteState` class.
2. Create a callback in `_CadastrarClienteState`
3. Pass the controller to the child `FormFinanceiro`.
4. Pass the callback to the child `FormCliente`.
5. Now, modify your onbuttonpressed function in `FormCliente` such that the callback is called when the button is pressed.
6. Finally in the callback method present in `_CadastrarClienteState`, clear the values using controllers.

Comment: thanks Joy Terence very good!  
but, there are many fields for pass, t would be complicated